# Using ethers.utils.FormatTypes.full returns object not string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, human-readable, ethers.js

I want to create a form from the Human-Readable ABI using the json file truffle creates. so the idea is to get the string Human-Readable ABI and then use regex to cut out and use the different parts to create my form. But using `ethers.utils.FormatTypes.full` does not return a string like the documentation suggest.

Here is my code:

```js
 const iface = await new ethers.utils.Interface(Bank.abi);
 iface.format(ethers.utils.FormatTypes.full);
```

expected output:

```js
[
 'function deposit() public payable',
 'function withdraw(uint256 _amount)',
 'function checkAssets() public view returns(uint256)'
];
```

actual output:
[image]
According to the documentation: [Converting Between Formats](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/utils/abi/formats/-%23-abi-formats--converting-between-formats)

> ethers.utils.FormatTypes.full ⇒ string.
> This is a full human-readable string, including all parameter names, any optional modifiers (e.g. indexed, public, etc) and white-space to aid in human readability.

But instead, it returns an object.
Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/abi/src.ts/fragments.ts#L310-L355), `format` will definitely return a string in all cases.

From your code excerpt, it's not clear what you're logging in the console.

It should be something like:

```
 const iface = await new ethers.utils.Interface(Bank.abi);
 console.log('Formatted ABI', iface.format(ethers.utils.FormatTypes.full));
```

From what you posted in the screenshot, it seems that you're logging the `iface` object itself.

I'd be happy for edit this answer if you provide the full code that you're using.

Comment: You are a legend, i was logging iface. Thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't see this one.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)